# second order soql injection checkmarx

Tags: soql, error

```apex
String keyword= 'abc'
String search = '\ '%' + String.escapeSingleQuotes(keyword) + '%\ '';
String query = 'Select Id From User Where firstName Like ' +search + 'Limit' + 10;
result = new Map<Id, sObject>(Database.query(query)); //source line
if(result.size() < 10) {
    r = result.keySet();
    query = 'Select Id From User Where lastName Like ' + search + ' Limit' + (10 - result.size());
    result.putAll(Database.query(query)) //destination line
}
```

getting errors on the query object not sure why?

Comment: You are missing few things. What is the variable which contains the string to be searched for? You would need to pass that to String.escapeSingleQuotes

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have variable `searchKeyword` variable that contains string to search for, try this.

```apex
String searchKeyword = 'metasync';
String search = '\'%' + String.escapeSingleQuotes(searchKeyword) + '%\'';
String query = 'Select Id From User Where firstName Like ' + search;
result = new Map<Id, sObject>(Database.query(query));
```