# Database.query() question

Tags: apex, soql, query, dynamic-soql, soql-injection

Is it ok to use String.escapeSingleQuotes() inside of a database.query() or do you need to create a new variable using the String.escapeSingleQuotes() first and then use the new variable in the Database.query()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to use variables if they are not required to be referred in another place. However, careful use of them can enhance the readability of the code to reduce the noise or complexity.

I assume you are alluding to this [question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/377056/second-order-soql-injection-checkmarx). That code can be simplified as

```
String searchKeyword = 'metasync';
result = new Map<Id, sObject>(Database.query('Select Id From User Where firstName Like ' + '\'%' + String.escapeSingleQuotes(searchKeyword) + '%\''));
```

As you can see, it may be considered less readable than other one.

Comment: No I meant more of after the query is built using previous code do you then need to create a new variable like queryEsc = String.escapleSingleQuotes(query) the using the Database.query(queryEsc) or just using Database.query(String.escapleSingleQuotes(query))

Comment: Note that you do not escape whole soql but individual values so `Database.query(String.escapleSingleQuotes(query))` probably not a correct usage. but more like `Database.query('select id, name from object where name = + \''String.escapleSingleQuotes(query) + '\')` is.